# How do I correctly find my exact job title?

Tags: new-job, internship

I am a college student with no prior work experience in the industry. I applied for a n internship as "Technical Intern" but later on they sent me an email saying the job I applied for is no longer available but there is different position available with *almost same* job description. Since I did not want to lose any opportunity, I agreed and they invited me over coding interview and later on offered me the job. The offer letter does not mention any exact title of my job. It only says "Summer Intern".

I don't know if this helps but my coding interview was a lot of Data Structures in Java (focusing mainly on algorithms such as Prim, Dijkstra etc.)

Since this is my first time in the industry, what would be a professional way to ask about my proper job title? I just felt like asking about my job title would make me look clueless and I def. do not want them to feel like that. Would be bad to makeup a technical job title in my resume if they only say "Summer Intern"? (For instance, I could say Software Developer Intern etc.)

Comment: Talk to HR about the internship. There is no problem in that.

Comment: If you're an intern why does it matter? If you want to put it on your resume then list it as an internship and list your job duties.

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs. Will do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**One may not exist**

Except for my job with a bank, my job titles for my resume during that period of my life were self-awarded simply because the official title was just either "Summer Intern" or "Intern."

Plenty of companies, especially smaller ones, don't go through the trouble of really distinguishing between what interns do internally. They just group them under one-three pay codes and that is that.  Many companies also just recruit 20 people and then figure out what to do with them once they have picked.

Ask HR about it, but I suspect that "Summer Intern" is your formal title.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've accepted this as an answer. Cheers!

Comment: +1: For interns job titles don't matter. When you're done with studies and entering the workforce, nobody will care whether you were a "Summer Intern" or "Intern" or "Tech Intern." They'll ask about what you learned during the internship.